# Mysql union optimization with subquery

Tags: mysql, optimization, limit, union

My problem is this query:

```
(SELECT    
     ID1,ID2,ID3,ID4,ID5,ID10,ID11,ID13,ID14,ID454,ID453,
     TIME,TEMP_ID,'ID_AUTO',PREDAJCA,VYTVORIL,MAIL,TEMP_ID_HASH,ID_SEND 
   FROM `load_send_calc` 
   WHERE `TEMP_ID` LIKE '$find%' 
     AND ACTIVE = 1 AND TEMP_ID > 0)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 
     ID1,ID2,ID3,ID4,ID5,ID10,ID11,ID13,ID14,ID454,ID453,TIME,'',
     ID_AUTO,'','','','','' 
  FROM `temp` 
  WHERE `ID_AUTO` LIKE '$find%' 
    AND `ID_AUTO` NOT IN (SELECT TEMP_ID 
                            FROM `load_send_calc` 
                            WHERE `load_send_calc`.ACTIVE = 1)
)
ORDER BY TIME  DESC LIMIT $limitFrom,$limitTo;
```

There are 18000 records in table `load_send_calc` and 3000 table `temp`. The query itself take more than 2 minutes to execute. Is there any way to optimize this time?

I already tried to put order into each subqueries but it didnt help significantly. I am really desperate so I really appreciate any kind of help.

EDIT: 
Here is EXPLAIN result :

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY load_send_calc  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    18394   Using where
2   UNION   temp    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1918    Using where
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  load_send_calc  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    18394   Using where
NULL    UNION RESULT    <union1,2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Using filesort
```

Comment: Please reformat sql query to be more readable. Ensure it is also printed as code block.

Comment: OK i reformated the query

Comment: you need to show the explain plan for your query

Comment: Have you indexed your tables, thats a major cause...

Comment: @pala_ How can i send formatted query in a table here? I got the results from EXPLAIN but i can put it here because it would not be readable

Comment: @indago Yes, both tables have primary key.

Comment: can your paste the table descriptions ?

Comment: just paste it in, select it all, and press `ctrl-k` to format as code. its not just primary keys that need indexes, @Redrif

Comment: @pala_ Seems like ctrl+k is not working for me so i will put the explain into the original question ok?

Comment: @Redrif, i think you havent understood me, edit your question and add the table description,, the create table statements for both tables, well formatted for us to be abe to read not in a comment

Comment: yeah thats not using a single index (and i meant add the explain to the question).

You should try indexing `load_send_calc.temp_id` and `load_send_calc.active`, and `temp.id_auto`. also this is unnecessary `AND TEMP_ID > 0` as you're already limiting it to `WHERE `TEMP_ID` LIKE '$find%' `

Comment: @pala_ ok so i am gonna try to put some indexes on those tables. I will reply as soon as i do it.

Comment: @indago you are right i havent :-) Explain is right there now.

Comment: @pala_ Thank you very much, after i created the indexes you mentioned it executes in less than 1 second. How can i mark your answer as accepted?

Comment: @indago Also thank you for showing me the right direction :-)

Comment: @Redrif answer added for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for adding your explain output - it tells us a lot. The query isn't using a single index, which is very bad for performance.  A very simple optimisation would be add indexes on the fields that are used in the `join`, and also in the `where` clauses.  In your case those fields would be:

`load_send_calc.temp_id`
`load_send_calc.active`
`temp.id_auto`

In addition to these, you have an unnecessary `AND TEMP_ID > 0`, since you are already limiting on the same field with `WHERE TEMP_ID LIKE '$find%'`

Answer (score 2):

3 things to speed it up:

```
INDEX(active, temp_id) -- significantly better than two separate indexes
```

`IN ( SELECT ... )` performs poorly, especially in old versions of MySQL.  Turn it into a `JOIN`.

Add a `LIMIT` to each `SELECT`.  For example:

```
( SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 80 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 80 )
             ORDER BY ... LIMIT 70, 10;
```

The inner ones have a limit of the max needed -- the outer's offset + limit.